# How do I replace the value in the <button> element with something else using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, replace

Here is the button im working with. Goal is to change the value name from "Apply Promo" to "Apply Promo Code".

```
<input id="btn_promo" ng-disabled="EditingDisabled" type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Apply Promo" ng-click="applyPromotion()" aria-disabled="false">
```

I tried both methods to accomplish this but none of them worked. Where in the document is the script supposed to be placed at? Header? Footer? I think it could be the placement but not really sure.

Methods tried:

```
document.getElementById('btn_promo').value = 'Apply Promo Code';
```

and

```
function  replaceBTN() {
  var newValue = document.getElementById("btn_promo").innerHTML;
  var res = newValue.replace("Apply Promo","Apply Promo Code");
  document.getElementById("btn_promo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

first method worked on itself in a blank document but once I tried applying it to the actual document it stopped working correctly.

--Have it working--
EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#btn_promo').attr('value','Apply Promo Code');
});
```

Comment: Just as an FYI: Java and Javascript are two different languages. I believe you mean javascript here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to change the value attr immediately when the page loads? or on a click event? Why not just change the html?

Try calling this script right before your close your body tag, or whenever you want the change to take place.

```
$('#btn_promo').attr('value', 'Apply Promo Code');
```

Comment: yes, i would like for it to change the value immediately. And I can't change the html since I do not have access to the DOM itself. I can only manipulate it and apply extra code to it. Its a pre-made website.

Comment: Try adding that line wherever you're allowed to add scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#Value) instead of `innerHTML`:

```js
function replaceBTN() {
  var newValue = document.getElementById("btn_promo").value;
  var res = newValue.replace("Apply Promo", "Apply Promo Code");
  document.getElementById("btn_promo").value = res;
}
replaceBTN();
```

```html
<input id="btn_promo" ng-disabled="EditingDisabled" type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Apply Promo" ng-click="applyPromotion()" aria-disabled="false">
```

Comment: Do you run the function `replaceBTN();` after the html? Can you run console.log("newValue: " + newValue);` inside the function after you have set it?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution since the DOM will need to load first before the jquery could be applied. The jquery code below cannot detect the the input's value if it doesn't load first. This will allow it to do that then apply whats necessary. For some reason this pre-generated webstore won't apply any jquery code until after everything is loaded.

```
/*Will check if the whole page is loaded*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*The value="Apply Promo" will be changed after everything is loaded*/
    $('input#btn_promo').attr('value','Apply Promo Code');
});
```